# Can I mix my own thinset mortar?

Tags: shower

Can I mix my own thin set to apply fibatape to backerboard?  I have Portland cement and sand.  Forgot to pick up thinset at store

Answer (score 2):

Most better thinset mortars are proprietary polymer-modified recipes which provide bond and flexibility that cement alone doesn't offer. Your home brew will be brittle and unreliable.

You could attempt to add modifiers to your mix, but the outcome will be a gamble. Also, any sand you use should be very fine or you'll have an unworkable grit.

Comment: I have used unmodified thinset on durock by accident one time and it was not much more than sand lightly stuck to the wall the next day. I scraped and washed it off and did it over with modified thinset.